# Magento 2 - Show swatches of simple products (out of stock) in configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, configurable-swatches

**Magento versión: 2.1.7**

I have a configurable product with **ALL** its simple products without stock.
I need to show in the configurable product the swatches of size / color (disabled) of their associated simple products.

Is this possible?

I already developed a modification and if at least 1 simple product has stock it shows all the swatches (available and not available).

The problem is if there's no stock of any simple product of configurable.

Comment: can you please share the code you have changed before?

Answer (score 3):

I've found this workaround:

I've overridden in my custom theme this phtml

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml`

Around line 35 you find

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->hasOptions() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container2'):?>
```

If you remove the condition `$_product->isSaleable()` you will get all the swatches visible

Comment: This doesn't work for me even after removing the condition, all swatches are not getting visible

Comment: cool! it's working

Comment: not working i apply this

Comment: v2.1.6 this doesn't help