# Magento2 Display all associated simple products if all of sizes are out of stock?

Tags: magento2, configurable-swatches

sizes options not showing on configurable products if all sizes out of stock.
Any way to show out of stock sizes?

Comment: Solution -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209316/magento-2-show-swatches-of-simple-products-out-of-stock-in-configurable-prod

Comment: I think `/var/www/html/CE/2.3.0/vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js`  file is responsible for this.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure to tell , may be that out-of-stack message issue occure based on the quantity of products.
so check your quantity in (simple products-configurable) through admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question, It is default Magento bug. (Maybe I am wrong ).

This issue is already reported in Magento Github ([Attributes - Display Out of Stock Products](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10454)). and this issue is **open** issue.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yo! Yo! Find Solution!
override `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml`

Create in below directory and open file

`app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Module>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/form.phtml`

**Remove**  `$_product->isSaleable()` **condition from line no.35**

[image]
[image]